# Wildcard not working in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I keep trying to use wildcards in a search in an android app, and keep running into errors.

I'm performing a search on my application using the string below:

```
Cursor c_name = b.query("namedrxns", new String[] { "_id", "name" },
              "name LIKE %?%", new String[] { query }, null, null, null);
```

when I use `name LIKE %?%` or `name=%?%` I get a "near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name FROM namedrxns WHERE name=%?%" error.

but with `name LIKE '%?%'` or `name='%?%'` I get instead "bind or column index out of range: handle 0x40cb70"

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What about adding the wildcarding to the variable being passed in, rather than having it in the query?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! That seems a bit silly to me, but never mind. I'd be happy to tick you if you put it as an answer :)

Comment: Sounds about right though. Bound string parameters basically will have quotes put around and stuff, so you might end up with something like name = %'David'% which is invalid SQL. My SQL knowledge isn't exactly up to par, so there is a little more work done here than what I can say, but this should give you an idea why it has to be done as OMG ponies describes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Append the `%` to the `query` parameter.

I.E.:

```
Cursor c_name = b.query("namedrxns", new String[] { "_id", "name" },
          "name LIKE ?", new String[] { "%"+query+"%" }, null, null, null);
```

Like Thomas Mueller already said, please note that `%` and `_` within the value still work as wildcards.

Comment: the complete value 'query' is escaped and put between '', so your % must be with it

Answer (score 5):

The following should work (but I didn't test it with SQLite):

```
"name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"
```

Please note that "%" and "_" within the value still work as wildcards.

Comment: Thanks, used CONCAT to make it work on serverside, but wouldn't work in SQLite on my android device. This was the correct way to do it for me.